# Custom PDF from scipy.stats.rv_continuous unwanted upper-bound

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, astronomy, probability-density

I am attempting to generate a random probability density function of QSO's of certain luminosity with the form:

1/( (L/L_B^* )^alpha + (L/L_B^* )^beta )

where L_B^*, alpha, and beta are all constants. To do this, the following code is used:

```
import scipy.stats as st

logLbreak = 43.88
alpha = 3.4
beta = 1.6


class my_pdf(st.rv_continuous):

    def _pdf(self,l_L): 
        #"l_L" in this is always log L        
        L = 10**(l_L/logLbreak)
        D = 1/(L**alpha + L**beta)
        return D

dist_Log_L = my_pdf(momtype = 0, a = 0,name='l_L_dist')


distro = dist_Log_L.rvs(size = 10000)
```

(L/L^* is rased to a power of 10 since everything is being done in a log scale)

The distribution is supposed to produce a graph that approximates [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4YlX.png), trailing off to infinity, but in reality the graph it produces looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91hAg.png) (10,000 samples). The upper bound is the same regardless of the amount of samples that are used. Is there a reason it is being restricted in the way it is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your PDF is not properly normalized.  The integral of a PDF over the domain must be 1.  Your PDF integrates to approximately 3.4712:

```
In [72]: from scipy.integrate import quad

In [73]: quad(dist_Log_L._pdf, 0, 100)
Out[73]: (3.4712183965415373, 2.0134487716044682e-11)

In [74]: quad(dist_Log_L._pdf, 0, 800)
Out[74]: (3.4712184965748905, 2.013626296581202e-11)

In [75]: quad(dist_Log_L._pdf, 0, 1000)
Out[75]: (3.47121849657489, 8.412130378805368e-10)
```

This will break the class's implementation of [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).  It will only generate samples from the domain up to where the integral of the PDF from 0 to x first reaches 1.0, which in your case is about 2.325

```
In [81]: quad(dist_Log_L._pdf, 0, 2.325)
Out[81]: (1.0000875374350238, 1.1103202107010366e-14)
```

That is, in fact, what you see in your histogram.

As a quick fix to verify the issue, I modified the `return` statement of the `_pdf()` method to:

```
        return D/3.47121849657489
```

and ran your script again. (In a real fix, that value will be a function of the other parameters.)  Then the commands

```
In [85]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [86]: plt.hist(distro, bins=31)
```

generates this plot:

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm pretty sure the constants I used are incorrect, so I would imagine if I actually implement them correctly the pdf will be a true pdf.